# Failed to serialize hudson.model.Actionable#Actions for class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-template-engine

I have a multi-brach pipeline that builds using the Jenkins Templating Engine plugin. When I try to write to currentBuild.description in my pipeline template (Jenkinsfile), I am getting a `Failed to serialize hudson.model.Actionable#Actions for class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun` error. I was able to do this successfully before I moved the pipeline code into the libraries that I created for the JTE plugin.

My pipeline template looks like:

```
...
try
timeout(time:10, unit:'MINUTES'){
initialize()
for (i in items){
if (i =="item1"){
currentBuild.description += "${i}" //fails
stage("Build ${i}"){
build()
}...
```

And my initialize.groovy step in the initialize library looks like:

```
currentBuild.description = "" //does not fails
...
checkout scm
...
def lastSuccessfulCommit = getLastSuccessfulCommit()
      def currentCommit = commitHashForBuild( currentBuild.rawBuild )
      if (lastSuccessfulCommit) {
  commits = sh(script: "git rev-list $currentCommit \"^$lastSuccessfulCommit\"",returnStdout: true).split('\n')
 ...
def getLastSuccessfulCommit() {
  def lastSuccessfulHash = null
  def lastSuccessfulBuild = currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousSuccessfulBuild()
  if ( lastSuccessfulBuild ) {
    lastSuccessfulHash = commitHashForBuild( lastSuccessfulBuild )
  }
  return lastSuccessfulHash
}
@NonCPS
def commitHashForBuild( build ) {
def scmAction = build?.actions.find { action -> action instanceof jenkins.scm.api.SCMRevisionAction }
return scmAction?.revision?.hash
}
```

Everything worked fine when all of these code were in the same Jenkinsfile but not anymore. The build now fails after the initialize method in the pipeline template executes. I have tried to set the description property in the pipeline template by creating a method, and annotating that method with @nonCPS but the error persists. I have also tried doing `currentBuild.description += "${i}".toString()` and `currentBuild.description = "description text"` but neither worked.

Full error log:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: hudson.AbortException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize hudson.model.Actionable#actions for class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ErrorStep$Execution.run(ErrorStep.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ErrorStep$Execution.run(ErrorStep.java:50)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousStepExecution.start(SynchronousStepExecution.java:38)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:319)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:193)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.call(WorkflowScript:5)
    at org.boozallen.plugins.jte.init.primitives.injectors.StepWrapperCPS.invoke(script16347498880811562650911.groovy:67)
    at org.boozallen.plugins.jte.init.primitives.injectors.StepWrapperCPS.call(script16347498880811562650911.groovy:41)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:111)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor143.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:89)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor148.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
Caused: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: hudson.AbortException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize hudson.model.Actionable#actions for class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun
    at org.boozallen.plugins.jte.init.primitives.injectors.StepWrapperCPS.invoke(script16347498880811562650911.groovy:69)
    at org.boozallen.plugins.jte.init.primitives.injectors.StepWrapperCPS.call(script16347498880811562650911.groovy:41)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:111)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.constructorCall(DefaultInvoker.java:25)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:97)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor143.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock$LocalVariable.get(LocalVariableBlock.java:39)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock.evalLValue(LocalVariableBlock.java:28)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$BlockImpl.eval(LValueBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock.eval(LValueBlock.java:16)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any idea what I may be doing wrong? Appreciate the help. Thanks.